# Ad Insights not return Ad Starts and Ad Ends in Facebook Marketing API

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-ads-api

On the **Ad Manager** at the Ad level, I am trying to get the dates where an **Ad Started** and **Stopped**.

So far, I am using **Ad Insights** in the API, but it only returns the query dates not the ones that the Ad was Active. So, it seems that it's not part of the queryable fields.

While using the **Power Editor** I can see such dates [Power Editor Shows Ad Starts Ad Stops](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jO6qg.png)

Is there any other way to get when a give Ad Starts and Stops, with the Ad ID for example?

Thank you,

H

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the only dates you can check are the `start_time` and `end_time` on the `AdSet` object, and this will give you the scheduled running time for an ad.

This will not always give you days that the ad had delivery, as it's possible to scheduled an adset, but leave it as paused.

Comment: Thats correct, I forgot to look on the AdSet field! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple dates you can check, but non of them will give you exactly what you want. Because ad could go paused/un-paused multiple times, it means, that it is no possible to get start and stop of that.

Dates you can get:

- on ad level there are "created" (when ad was created) and "updated"
  (when ad was last time updated) dates.
- on ad insight level you can see "date_start" (first stats appear) and "date_stop" (last day of requested period).

Only idea i can suggest is to query insights for lifetime, spitted by days. In return you will get list of days when your ad was active and was generating statistic. If you ad was active for 5 days, but actual lifetime was 30 days you will get array with 5 items, so you can take first and last.

This  logic is applied to any level: campaigns/adsets/ads.

Comment: How I could query lifetime inside the _param_ option?

`my_account.get_ad_sets(fields=fields, params=params)`

Comment: Its depend on your code. On Facebook API side you need to use two parameters date_preset=lifetime and time_increment=1

Comment: I am new in FB Mkt API, and now I understand better the architecture of Campaign->AdSet->Ad. But, whats the difference between read a created AdSetor or Ad and get the insights of a given Ad or AdSet?

Comment: Adset can contain multiple ads, so if you request stats by adset you can see list of ad stats, you don't need to call facebook multiple times to get all ads. Same with campaign it may contain multiple adsets.